# Very starting with Bitbucket - how to move my local dev folders in and keep history?

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I'm very new to bitbucket, git and any sort of version control (like hello world new.)  Basically till now whatever little bits I've done I've simply version named files on my local file system.  And I'm just doing powershell and some routeros scripts so my dev is fairly basic too.
Here is a recent example:

[image]

Now I'm starting to feel a bit more serious/ambitious.  I've begun using VS Code and want to move this 'project' to a bitbucket repo both for safety and for learning purposes.
You see the files above date-stamped and also versioned with numbers that match what I do in my changelogs within the file.

The .deploy folder is a staging area of sorts because there are changes to the script (user defined variables, etc.) that are private.  This is sort of prep for publishing these publicly (or at least trying to think that way for if/when.)

So how do I go about moving my very basic home-brewed versioning to bitbucket and keep/convert my versions/history into something suitable?

Sorry, I know this is probably so very newb but that's where I'm at in the learning curve atm and searching didn't really find anything addressing this particular want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by creating a Git repository locally first:

```
git config --global user.name aName
git config --global user.email anEmail

cd /path/to/my/project
git init .
```

At this point, check first if you need to add *everything* to the new local Git repository: if ".deploy" has only *generated* content, add it to a `.gitignore`, along with other [Powershell gitignore directives](https://www.gitignore.io/api/powershell):

```
echo "/.deploy/">.gitignore
echo "*.zip">>.gitignore
echo "*.dll">>.gitignore
```

Then add and commit.

```
git add .
git commit -m
```

Finally, create an empty repo on BitBucket side, and copy the https URL, to add to your own repo:

```
git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/aUser/aNewRepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

---

> Where in this does git get to "know" that these are versions of the same file?

It does not: I didn't looked closely enough to your question to note that it was the same file, backed up with different names.

In order to add that file with its history, add the oldest version of that file first:

```
git add --force 2018...veam_Backup_VMs.ps1
```

And rename it to the actual file name:

```
git mv 2018...veam_Backup_VMs.ps1 veam_Backup_VMs.ps1
```

And commit:

```
git commit -m "Import oldest version of veam_Backup_VMs.ps1"
```

For the next version, from oldest to newest, simply copy over the imported by by a more recent file, renamed to match `veam_Backup_VMs.ps1`.
Once the file is overwritten (no `git` commands here, just a regular `cp`), you can then add and commit. And repeat for all the versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer will go try now but want to clarify: 
 Where in this does git get to "know" that these are versions of the same file?  Or am I just dumping everything in as one big lump and (doing what?) going forward?  Thanks.

Comment: @JoelAZ I have edited the answer to address your specific use-case.

Comment: Thank you VonC!  I will go make a mess (aka try this out) now.  Just to be clear - "backup" in this context is part of the name of the script (it runs backups of VM via scheduler).  The datestamp at the front and the version number at the tail of the filenames denote the 'versioning'.  I think you've given me what I need though to get through for now.  Thank you!

Comment: @JoelAZ OK, no need to add *Backup* to .gitignore then.

Comment: Yes of course.  I just want to try the solution(s) before I close out the question as answered.  I appreciate the effort and contribution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174586/discussion-between-joelaz-and-vonc).